# Audio/ Video calling in android with jitsi

Tags: android, android-studio, android-developer-api, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am working on a chat application on which I have to do the video/Audio call. After lots of R&D I have found to go with `Jitsi` platform. I am referring to the Atalk code so I am having some NDK issues which is a bit difficult for me to solve.

I am facing this NDK error on my Android application using the jitsi video library:

```
Process 'command '/Users/SmackVideoCall/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I am following refreance code Atalk (https://github.com/cmeng-git/atalk-android))

Comment: What's your specific question? What did you try to resolve it and what didn't work?

Comment: Hello Cloned 
    
     I am facing this ndk error on my android application run (Process 'command '/Users/SmackVideoCall/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2) using jitsi video library.

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make additions and improvements to your question